# String to System.Windows.Forms.Control

Tags: string, type-conversion, controls, tooltip, picturebox

I swear I tried to find an answer but I couldn't apply to this problem.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_PcInfo.Rows)
{
   string nome = "tag" + row.Cells["TAG"].Value.ToString();
                
   if (tableLayoutPanel7.Controls.ContainsKey(nome))
   {
      ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
      tt.SetToolTip(this.Controls[nome] as PictureBox, "Your username"); ==> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name'
   }
}
```

I get ==> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name'